# Posting an image and textual based data to a wcf service

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

I have a requirement to write a web service that allows me to post an image to a server along with some additional information about that image.

I'm completely new to developing web services (normally client side dev) so I'm a little stumped as to what I need to look into and try.

How do you post binary data and plain text into a servic?
What `RequestFormat` should I use?
It looks like my options are xml or json. Can I use either of these?

Bit of a waffly question but I just need some direction rather than a solution as I can't seem to find much online.

Answer (score 1):

After reading this [guide to building restuful services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) I figured I was going about the problem the wrong way.  The image and text are actually two seperate resources and so should probably be handled seperately.  I now have a service that uploads an image and returns a uri to that image and a seperate service to post textual data relating to that image along with the uri to that image.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't have experience with WCF, I can tell you a painless way to handle POSTing/PUTting of binary data in a REST API (especially one with a mix of text + binary) is to encode the binary data as **base64** and treat it much like any other text data in your API.

*Yes, there is a slight overhead with base64 in terms of size and an additional encode/decode process, however, base64 is typically only **1.37x** larger than binary.*

I find in many cases the overhead is well worth avoiding the pain that can be involved with  binary data in APIs, especially when you need to POST/PUT a combination of binary and text data.  If you wanted to POST an image and additional meta/text data you could easily do so with a json string ("image" would be your base64 encoded image)...

```
{
    "image":"aGVsbG8...gd29ybGQ=", 
    "user" : 1234, 
    "sub_title": "A picture from my trip to Pittsburgh"
}
```

This is by no means the best solution for all cases, and as I said, I'm not a WCF expert, but it's certainly something to consider in the general case to make your life easier.

Comment: +1. Yeah did look into this as it looked perfect.  Only problem was that my service is going to be used by a variety of different platforms (win 7 phone, android, iphone) and i'm as yet not sure if they all provide classes to encode as base64.  I may well head down this route as i investigate how easy this encoding is.

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if there wasn't something available for base64 encoding on android and iphone.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebServiceHost in WCF 3.5 then you need to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx).  If you have to use WCF to do HTTP based stuff then try and get onto .Net 4.  I believe they have made a whole lot of things much easier.

If you are stuck with 3.5, welcome to a world of pain.  Find everything you can written by Aaron Skonnard on the subject.  And as I suggested in the comments of the other question, learn how to use SvcTrace.

Comment: @Darrel Miller .Net 4 is fine. Any resources on how this could make my life easier?

Comment: @James I took a quick look but didn't find anything specific to POSTing raw data.  You may be still stuck with Carlos' solution.